# Каким образом я могу получить список пользователей для обработки в цикле?

Tags: linux, bash, администрирование, резервное-копирование

Здравствуйте. Как я могу получить список пользователей для обработки в цикле?

```
    #!/bin/sh
    #Get list of all important users
    LIST=ls  /home/u*
    #Add timestamp
    TS=$(date +"%d-%m-%Y")
    #Backup files
#List - список пользователей, client - имя пользователя
    for client in LIST
    do
    sudo tar -cfp --acls "/backup/$CLIENT/$TS.tar.gz" "/home/$CLIENT/web"
    done
```

Comment: *man getent* для списка пользователей, и книжку для понимания синтаксиса ЯП shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы предложил воспользоваться программой `rdiff-backup`. Она и сжимает и отметки времени сохраняет и с `ugo` работает.

```
rdiff-backup /чё/копируем /куда/копируем
```

Answer (score 1):

судя по приведённому скрипту, вам нужны не пользователи, а подкаталоги внутри каталога `/home`, имена которых начинаются с буквы `u`.

получить их можно, к примеру, командой `cd /home && ls -d u*`.

чтобы записать в переменную то, что вернёт команда, надо обернуть команду в оператор оболочки `$(...)` ([*command substitution*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03)):

```
переменная=$(cd /home && ls -d u*)
```

---

> ```
> for client in LIST
> ```

здесь, видимо, подразумевалась итерация по токенам, содержащимся в переменной `LIST`, а не по списку из одного элемента (`LIST`). тогда надо указать, что используется значение переменной, добавив `$` перед её именем:

```
for client in $LIST
```

---

> ```
> sudo tar -cfp --acls "/backup/$CLIENT/$TS.tar.gz" "/home/$CLIENT/web"
> ```

здесь, видимо, подразумевалось использование описанной чуть выше переменной `client` (а не `CLIENT`). будьте внимательны: в posix-совместимых оболочках регистр в имени переменной имеет значение.

Comment: Со списком разобрался.Подскажите пожалуйста, почему появляются эти ошибки при выполнении скрипта? Я понимаю, что они говорят о том, что скрипту не удалось найти файл /backup/u34/09-08-2017.tar.gz - но это естественно, ведь архив ещё не создан!
https://pastebin.com/gr1Ezx9M

Comment: 1. какие «эти ошибки»? 2. если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки в правом верхнем углу страницы.